# how to save and pass a double variable in asp.net c# mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, c#-4.0

Still having trouble with google maps in asp.net C# 4.0 mvc 3. 
So now, I can view the google map in my webpage but when I put my coordinates, the google map doesn't appear anymore. I assume there must be something with the passing of my data and such? I am using sql server 2008. In my google map table, I have set longitude and latitude as integer because it doesn't have a double category. What should I do? Any advice/ suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

This is my code for my google map View

```
        @{
        ViewBag.Title = "GMAP";
        Layout = "~/Views/Home/Gmap.cshtml";
        }

        <h2>GMAP</h2>
        @section Scripts { 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        }

        @section Styles { 
            html { height: 80% } 
            body { height: 80%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
            #map_canvas { height: 80% } 
        }

        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@ViewData["Latitude"], @ViewData["Longitude"] );
            var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
            }

            $(function () {
            initialize();
            }); 
        </script>
```

Here is the code for my Google Map Controller

```
    public ActionResult GMAP(int id){
        var dataContext = new transDataContext();
        Double Longitude = (Double)(from t in dataContext.TransactionModels
        where t.id.Equals(id)
        select t.longitude).Single();
        Double latitude = (Double)(from t in dataContext.TransactionModels
        where t.id.Equals(id)
        select t.latitude).Single();
        ViewData["Longitude"] = Longitude;
        ViewData["Latitude"] = latitude;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> In my google map table, I have set longitude and latitude as integer because it doesn't have a double category.

You have answered your own question. Lat and Long have to be doubles. -0.156 Long is going to end up as zero.

Comment: So -0.156 Long is going to end up as zero? Then the coordinates are going to be incorrect? :\

Comment: Yes, but I am confused about the integer bit because you could not store that value as a database int anyway, so if you looked at your raw data using Sql, it should already show the values truncated, without decimal points. The type you should be using for storing them in the database is 'float'.